# Is my code for a forum page vulnerable for sql injections?

Tags: php, sql

This is the backend code for the page where you upload a post. I have already tried to do a sql attack on this page, but it didn't work.

```php
<?php
include_once 'includes1/dbh.inc.php';
session_start();
//*skåd ifall man är inloggad *//
if (isset($_POST['topic_submit'])) {
    $newFileName = "annons"; //Här ska egentligen vara $_POST['topic_title'];//
    if (empty($newFileName)) {
        $newFileName = "annons";
    } else {
        $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
    }
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        $title = $_POST['topic_title'];
        $content = $_POST['topic_content'];
        $creator = $_SESSION['UserName'];
        $imageNamn = $_POST['filenamn'];
        $imageMail = $_POST['filemail'];
        $imageNummer = $_POST['filenummer'];
        $imagePris = $_POST['filepris'];
        $imagestad = $_POST['filestad'];

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $file["name"];
    $fileType = $file["type"];
    $fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
    $fileError = $file["error"];
    $fileSize = $file["size"];

    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "image/jpg");

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
          if ($fileSize < 2000000000) {
            $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = "img/gallery/" . $imageFullName;

            include_once 'includes1/dbh.inc.php';

            if (empty($title) || empty($content) || empty($imageNamn) || empty($imageMail) || empty($imagestad) || empty($imagePris)) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?upload=empty");
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM gallery;";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                    echo "SQL statement failed!";
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO topics (category_id, topic_title, topic_creator, topic_date, topic_reply_date, imgFullNameGallery, topic_pris) VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$title."', '".$creator."', now(), now(), '".$imageFullName."', '".$imagePris."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $new_topic_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO gallery (category_id, topic_id, post_creator, titleGallery, descGallery, namnGallery, emailGallery, nummerGallery, prisGallery, stad, post_date, imgFullNameGallery)
                     VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$new_topic_id."', '".$creator."', '".$title."', '".$content."', '".$imageNamn."', '".$imageMail."', '".$imageNummer."', '".$imagePris."', '".$imagestad."', now(), '".$imageFullName."')";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    $sql3 = "UPDATE categories SET last_post_date=now(), last_user_posted='".$creator."' WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
                    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                        echo "SQL statement failed!";
                    } else {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssss", $cid, $new_topic_id, $creator, $title, $content, $imageNamn, $imageMail, $imageNummer, $imagePris, $imagestad, $imageFullName);
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

                        header("location: view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$new_topic_id);          
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
        echo "File size is too big!";
        exit();
        }
    } else {
    echo "You had an error!";
    exit();
    }
} else {
    echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense, My code actually works right now.

Comment: Avoiding repeating what Your Common Sense has said you should also consider reordering your logic to make it a bit easier. I suggest starting by early exiting rather than having nested ifs. Something like `if (!in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) { echo "Invalid file type"; exit(1); }` would mean you don't need to have your logic indented 6 levels deep as the exit means it'll never run other code. This also helps when you eventually come around to putting stuff into functions and classes since you can easily move sections of the code without breaking the indenting.

Comment: Your question title is not meant to indicate your concern for your code, but what your code does.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes, it is.

For some reason you put everything upside-down: where you don't need a prepared statement (for a constant query) you are using it, but where a prepared statement is mandatory - for a query that uses variables - you don't.

But I would say, it is not the main problem of this code. The main problem is this code being a total mess. There are two blocks of code that do absolutely nothing useful, one of them even fails, but you don't notice it.

I would review only a database interaction part

#### 1. Useless code

The following block of code does absolutely nothing

```
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM gallery;";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed!";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
```

it takes you $rowCount which is nowhere used. You can safely take this code away.

Another block,

```
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                    echo "SQL statement failed!";
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssss", $cid, $new_topic_id, $creator, $title, $content, $imageNamn, $imageMail, $imageNummer, $imagePris, $imagestad, $imageFullName);
```

is also doing nothing useful (as you are already executed this query), and even fails on the bind_param part, because of the flawed

#### 2. Error reporting

There are two things you are doing wrong in regard of error reporting

- using procedural interface that **silently** fails on errors
- checking the function results manually

To fix these issues, you have to use OOP syntax and add a specific command to your mysqli connection code,

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

(just for reference, here is a [canonical example for mysqli connect](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) I wrote).

After that, all MySQL errors will pop up automatically, therefore you won't have to check every function's result manually.

#### 3. SQL injection.

Finally to the SQL injection. The rules are simple:

- if your query doesn't accept any variables, then you don't have to run it using a prepared statement. Use a regular query() instead.
- if your query accepts **any** variables, then it must be executed using prepared statement

Now you can see that if `SELECT * FROM gallery` had any meaning, you would have run it using `query()`, not a prepared statement. But as it is just useless, we won't run this query at all.

All other queries must be run using prepared statements:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO topics (category_id, topic_title, topic_creator, topic_date, topic_reply_date, imgFullNameGallery, topic_pris) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,now(), now(),?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $cid, $title, $creator, $imageFullName, $imagePris);
$stmt->execute();
$new_topic_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

$sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (category_id, topic_id, post_creator, titleGallery, descGallery, namnGallery, emailGallery, nummerGallery, prisGallery, stad, post_date, imgFullNameGallery)
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $cid, $new_topic_id, $creator, $title, $content, $imageNamn, $imageMail, $imageNummer, $imagePris, $imagestad, $imageFullName);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "UPDATE categories SET last_post_date=now(), last_user_posted=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $creator, $cid);
$stmt->execute();

move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);
header("location: view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$new_topic_id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, I'm a begginer at this so it's very helpful all the things you wrote thanks again!!!